# Shell script to compare multiple files from a directory but attach only the mismatched files as an email attachment

Tags: bash, scripts

I am comparing multiple files from a directory. Among the files some are matched some are mismatched.
I am able to output the difference using diff command. I want to email the mismatched files as attachments.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR1=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/inf
DIR2=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/gen/genB

DEST_DIR1=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/moved/cmpinf
DEST_DIR2=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/moved/cmpgen

export RESULT=$1

for FILE1 in `ls $DIR1`
do
    if [ ! -f $DIR2/$FILE1 ]; then
        echo "  $FILE1 exists in $DIR1 but not found in $DIR2. Skipping file." >> $RESULT
    else
        echo "  Comparing $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1." >> $RESULT
        diff -B $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1 >> $RESULT
        #diff $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1 >>RESULT
        echo "  Done comparing $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1." >> $RESULT

        mv $DIR1/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR1
        mv $DIR2/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR2
        echo "  Done moving files" >> $RESULT

    fi
done

for FILE2 in `ls $DIR2`
do
    if [ ! -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]; then
        echo "  $FILE2 exists in $DIR2 but not found in $DIR1. Skipping file." >> $RESULT
    fi
done

echo "  Done comparing." >> $RESULT
zip -r $DEST_DIR1/downlaod.zip $DEST_DIR1/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR2/$FILE1
mail -a $DEST_DIR1/downlaod.zip xvz@abc.com
```

Thank you

Comment: Your script seems to start in the middle of something.

Comment: I posted my entire script

Comment: Shouldn't you be running the `zip` command inside the first loop?

Comment: Okay. But how will I make sure that the zip command will zip the mismatched files only?

Comment: how are you making sure you're only moving and listing the mismatched files now?

Comment: I am moving all the files now. But after comparison I want to attach only the mismatched ones

Comment: Should I be using if-else with the diff, like
diff $DEST_DIR1/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR2/$FILE1 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Files are the same"
else
  zip -r $DEST_DIR1/downlaod.zip $DEST_DIR1/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR2/$FILE1
fi

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It builds the list of differing files while cycling through the first loop and then uses a different zip command to zip them up.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR1=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/inf
DIR2=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/gen/genB

DEST_DIR1=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/moved/cmpinf
DEST_DIR2=/usr/local/apps/B2B/filecompare/moved/cmpgen

export RESULT=$1
touch different.txt

for FILE1 in `ls $DIR1`
do
    if [ ! -f $DIR2/$FILE1 ]; then
        echo "  $FILE1 exists in $DIR1 but not found in $DIR2. Skipping file." >> $RESULT
    else
        echo "  Comparing $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1." >> $RESULT
        diff -B $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1 >> $RESULT
        #diff $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1 >>RESULT
        echo "  Done comparing $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE1." >> $RESULT

        # NEW: register if there is a diff
        is_diff=$(diff -q $DIR1/$FILE1 $DIR2/$FILE2 >/dev/null; echo $?)

        # NEW: build a list of the files that are different
        if [ "$is_diff" -gt 0 ]; then
            echo $DEST_DIR1/$FILE1 >> different.txt
            echo $DEST_DIR2/$FILE1 >>  different.txt
        fi


        mv $DIR1/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR1
        mv $DIR2/$FILE1 $DEST_DIR2
        echo "  Done moving files" >> $RESULT

    fi
done

for FILE2 in `ls $DIR2`
do
    if [ ! -f $DIR1/$FILE2 ]; then
        echo "  $FILE2 exists in $DIR2 but not found in $DIR1. Skipping file." >> $RESULT
    fi
done

echo "  Done comparing." >> $RESULT
# NEW: zip the file list of differing files
zip $DEST_DIR1/download.zip -@ < different.txt
mail -a $DEST_DIR1/download.zip xvz@abc.com
```